# ListView doesn't show text from ListView.ItemSource binding in Xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms

I follow Microsoft's Xamarin guide populating data in ListView
Here's [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/listview/?tutorial-step=2&tabs=vswin)!

In a guide, They use ItemSource property of ListView in .xaml

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" />
```

And in the constructor of this page, they create List of Objects, Add data, and bind context.

```
     public IList<Monkey> Monkeys { get; private set; }
     public MainPage()
     {
     Monkeys = new List<Monkey>{
            new Monkey
            {
                Name = "Baboon",
                Location = "Africa & Asia",
                ImageUrl = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Papio_anubis_%28Serengeti%2C_2009%29.jpg/200px-Papio_anubis_%28Serengeti%2C_2009%29.jpg"
            }, ... }

     BindingContext = this;
     }
```

When I run debug program a ListView will show the cell without any text.

## background what I've tried

First, I think it's about the text color problem, so I change the background color of ListView but the ListView is still blank of any text.

Second, I think a ListView doesn't find a binding object Monkeys but when I count the cell in ListView (with is blank of text) the cell count equals to the number of objects I added into the Monkeys List.

Thrid I think when I use

> ItemSource="{Binding Monkeys}"

it will show text from a ToString() method of the class but it's not, then I edit code from using ItemSource property in xaml

> ItemSource="{Binding Monkeys}"

and set an ItemSource property of ListView directly in xaml.cs instead

> ListView.ItemSource = Monkeys.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

and then the text is showing.

The problem is why the code doesn't run as expected or what I miss it from the tutorial. I use Xamarin Form version 3.4.0.1008975
Thank you.

Comment: you generally need to supply an ItemTemplate when using a ListView.  Their sample seems to get around this by adding a ToString() method to their Monkey class - have you done that?

Comment: yes I have already add ToString() method at Monkey class

Comment: have you tried adding an ItemTemplate?

Comment: After I add ItemTemplate the code works fine now. Thank you. how can I mark the comment as an answer?